# Parser for Expression Filter

Tags: java, sql

I have table column with expression filter applied. Is there any existing parser that would allow me to parse this column? the column can contain simple conditions such as

```sql
PROPERTY = 'name' AND PROPERTY2 = 'something else'
```

or more advanced like

```sql
(PROPERTY IN ('foo', 'bar') 
  AND (PROPERTY IN ('foo1', 'bar2') OR OTHER_PROPERTY IN ('etc'))
```

It would totally suffice if it would return list of properties in expression and either value (in case of = operator) or list of all values (even if one property appears more than once in expression). Is there such parser available or do I have to write it myself?

Comment: From your description I understand you are storing expressions in a database table but are you looking for a parser to use in SQL or Java? Are the expressions, which are stored in the table, then used in a subsequent SQL query built by your Java code? Please add some more information as to how you are using these expressions, thanks.

Comment: Yes, you're right, there is expression stored in db column and I also have some parsing and further processing of the expression in Java code. Currently the parsing is very simplistic and rules are hardcoded and rely on knowledge how expressions are constructed (in other part of code so for example it is hardcoded that "SOME_PROPERTY=\\d+" which would cause problem if it is changed to "SOME_PROPERTY IN (1,2,3) which is legal in column). I'd like to enhance it so that it'd be able to parse more extensively.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [jOOQ's parser](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-parser/). Given this requirement:

> It would totally suffice if it would return list of properties in expression and either value (in case of = operator) or list of all values (even if one property appears more than once in expression)

You could run this piece of code:

```java
Map<Field<?>, List<QueryPart>> result =
DSL.using(SQLDialect.DEFAULT)
   .parser()
   // Parse the SQL string to a jOOQ expression tree
   .parseCondition(
       """
       (PROPERTY IN ('foo', 'bar')
           AND (PROPERTY IN ('foo1', 'bar2') OR OTHER_PROPERTY IN ('etc')))
       """)
   // Traverse the jOOQ expression tree using Traversers and Collectors
   // You can also traverse the tree using imperative APIs, of course
   .$traverse(Traversers.collecting(
       Collectors.filtering(p -> p instanceof InList 
                              || p instanceof CompareCondition,
           Collectors.groupingBy(p ->
                 p instanceof InList<?> i
               ? i.$arg1()
               : p instanceof CompareCondition<?> c
               ? c.$arg1()
               : null,
               Collectors.mapping(p ->
                     p instanceof InList<?> i
                   ? i.$arg2()
                   : p instanceof CompareCondition<?> c
                   ? c.$arg2()
                   : null,
                   Collectors.toList()
               )
           )
       )
   ));
System.out.println(result);
```

It produces this output:

```
{PROPERTY=['foo', 'bar', 'foo1', 'bar2'], OTHER_PROPERTY=['etc']}
```

Not sure if this exactly matches your requirements, but it should be straightforward to tweak the code accordingly

Disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOQ

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how you are developing your project. But if your are using hibernate you can use criteria queries. 
[Cirteria queries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html)